# Creating a static image fallback if Vimeo video doesn't load

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, vimeo

I am trying to figure out a way to create a static image fallback in the case that Vimeo's severs are down.  It's a rare occurrence, but the video is a major element and being used as a homepage background.  When it goes down it displays a black screen with an error message and completely throws off the page design.

I unfortunately don't have a lot of experience with embedding Vimeo on a site.  Is there a way to detect if the video is loading/playing correctly, and if not show a static image in its place?  Here is the existing code for the embedded video being loaded in an iframe.

```
<div class="vimeoVideo">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/---------?byline=0&amp;badge=0&amp;background=1&amp;title=0" style="width: 100vw; height: 56.25vw; min-height: 100vh; min-width: 177.77vh; position: absolute;top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" allowfullscreen scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, I've never seen a way to check if a third party video is working correctly programmatically speaking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I was figuring there probably wasn't a viable solution for it, but worth looking into just in case.